# private and protected methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, access-specifier

The following code works:

```
class MyClass
  def method_a
    method_b
  end

  private
  def method_b
    puts "Hello!"
  end
end

m = MyClass.new
m.method_a
```

Changing the call to method_b to `self.method_b` however does not work:

```
def method_a
  self.method_b
end
```

I get a `NoMethodError`. I'm under the impression that `self` just resolves to the instance of the class when inside an instance method. **Why does `self.method_b` cause problems?**

Note: `self.method_b` works when `private` is changed to `protected`.

Note: if the above methods are changed to class methods then calling `self.method_b` from method_a doesn't throw the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me; is that a class, not a `def`?

Comment: You're correct. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how `private` methods work in Ruby. They cannot be called with an explicit receiver *(unless it is a setter method; see below)*.

Read more in the section on *[Access Control](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#accesscontrol)* from the Pickaxe.

Private methods whose names end with an `=` *may* be invoked using `self.method_name = ...` as this is necessary to differentiate them from setting a local variable:

```
class Foo
  def try
    set_foo(1)            # Invokes private method
    self.set_foo(2)       # ERROR: private method `set_foo' called for ...
    self.send(:set_foo,3) # Invokes private method

    bar = 1               # Sets local variable
    self.bar = 2          # Invokes private method
    self.send(:bar=,3)    # Invokes private method
  end

  private
    def set_foo(v)
      @foo = v
    end
    def bar=(v)
      @bar = v
    end
end

Foo.new.bar = 42          # ERROR: private method `bar=' called for ...
```

Answer (score 3):

That's just how Ruby works: when you provide an explicit object reference, `NoMethodError` is raised to show the code is breaking intent. You could do a `self.send` and it would work.

Without the explicit reference, Ruby doesn't do the same visibility check; see [this](http://ruby.runpaint.org/methods#advisory-privacy) and/or [this](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/23/method-visibility-in-ruby) for a bit more detail.

Nutshell is that private methods can't be called with an explicit receiver, even if it's `self`.